# Yii2 Listview how to display data in view

Tags: php, listview, yii, yii2

**Greetings**

**I want to display data from my Atividades model in Yii2**

**My AtividadesController has the following code for actionView2**

```
public function actionView2()
{
    $query = new Query;
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query->from('Atividades'),
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ],
    ]);

    // get the posts in the current page
    $posts = $dataProvider->getModels();
    return $this->render('view2', ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 'posts' => $posts]);

}
```

**And in my View 2 i have the following List View that appears with the message showing 4 of 4 items, but doesn't shows the items**

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]); ?>
```

**In Y1.xx i had a property called 'attributes' for display the model fields**

**How can i display the model fileds in Yii2 inside this Listview**

**Many thanks in advance**

Comment: The Bold and the Beautiful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I have solved it by myself :)**

**It was not hard**

**In my View2 Written the following code**

```
 <?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_view2',
]); ?>
```

**And then duplicated an original view file, changed its name to _view2, put it in the same folder, and style it has needed**

**In my ActividadesController changed the actionView2 code to:**

```
public function actionView2()
{
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Atividades::find(),
    'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => 20,
],
]);

// get the posts in the current page
$posts = $dataProvider->getModels();
return $this->render('view2', ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
}
```

**_View2 code**

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        //'id',
        'atividade',
        'descricao:ntext',
        //'ativo',
    ],
]) ?>
```

**SOLVED**